# Randomly sorted 1d array(google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How would one return a randomly sorted version of another 1d array, ignoring empty cells? For example, a 1x26(vertical) array of the alphabet in column A could be sorted into a random order in column B.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Specify your range in the lambda call once in this case `A2:A57`

we are using `RANDARRAY` with the same length of the input as a sort column in the `SORT` function.

```
=LAMBDA(rg, QUERY(SORT({rg,RANDARRAY(ROWS(rg),1)},2,1)," Select Col1 where Col1 <> '' "))
       (A2:A57)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this. It generates a "fictional" column with random values and sort your column by them:

```
=SORT(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),BYROW(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),LAMBDA(e,RANDOM())),1)
```

Comment: Sadly, I’m using the app, which doesn’t support the lambda function. Is it possible without this?

Comment: I've actually posted this with my phone and Android app. Have you tried it?

Answer (score -1):

You may try:

```
=QUERY(SORT(A1:A26,INDEX(WEEKDAY(SEQUENCE(26),3)),1),"WHERE Col1<>''")
```

- `RAND` functions recalculate on every sheet change. this is more of an approach to create a `static` style pseudo-random array to use within sort and randomize the column A

[image]